# How to suppress unused C library functions in SDCC compiler?

Tags: microcontroller, embedded, compiler, stm8, open-source

Previously I used the COSMIC compiler for STM8 development. In a cosmic compiler, there is an argument called **'SPLIT'** which can be passed while using it on the command line. This allows the linker to suppress unused functions from the included libraries, decreasing the overall size of the code by more than 50-70%.

I just started using the open-source compiler SDCC. I did not find any such feature that was there in the cosmic compiler. So though I want to use a single function from the C library, all other unused functions too occupy the space in controller flash. There is an argument that can be passed **'--opt-code-size'** but it does not suppress unused functions.

So is there any other method to suppress unused functions to save the code memory?

Comment: GCC has linker options for this. If SDCC has, I would expect it's documentation to describe them.

Comment: unused symbols not being included in the binary sounds like a standard feature of any compiler / linker of the last 20 years? SDCC possibly does this by default. Have you verified it's not happening? How are you linking your result?

Comment: Yes, I verified by doing different experiments. Now I got a reply from the developer of the SDCC for the same question I posted on the SDCC forum. I put their reply as an answer to this question.

Comment: what were these experiments? The text you quote suggests that dead-code elimination *does* indeed happen.

Comment: From experiments, I verified that '--opt-code-size'  does not remove unused symbols.  Add a function in the c library and import it to the main C file and then checked the map file generated after linking and that added unused function was occupying the space

Comment: It is usually achieved by placing each function in it's own code section *while compiling the library*. Then the linker can eliminate the unused *sections*. It cannot eliminate functions from which are compiled into the same sections. If the standard library is not compiled this way, then, well.. switch to GCC. Luckily it supports virtually any architecture these days (if not officially, then there are unofficial ports).

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to eliminate the unused function while linking.
I got the answer to the above question posted on the official forum of SDCC and it is as follows:

> The linker sdld does not support function-level linking. The standard
> library, therefore, uses one source file per function.

So we can make a header file which include all functions in that library and then make single c files containing single functions .  Header file must be included in each C file so that we can call other functions of same library. Then compile all individual C files. SDCC can then eliminate the unused functions as they are in separate modules

Comment: That is suggestive. But I'm not sure it answers your own question. Does the linker support trimming if the functions are placed one to a file? I can't tell from that. It's suggestive that those writing the standard library went to some trouble in order to create one file for every function. They would not do that unless there is a good reason. But it's not clear from what you captured. Just suggestive.

Comment: actually, it says the opposite of what the original question claims: The linker indeed does not support dead-code elimination in symbols when they are in the same object file. Because of that, the standard library is structured in a way that **allows** for dead-code elimination, by putting all functions into different units. [Thread on the sdcc-user mailing list](https://sourceforge.net/p/sdcc/mailman/sdcc-user/thread/532755D9.2070307%40spth.de/#msg32111912).

Comment: For understanding, I opened the inbuilt library directory of the compiler. in that directory, there was a different c file for each function in math.h  library for example there are files such as sinf.c , cosf.c , tanf.c etc . each file contain only that individual function and math.h was included in each file

Comment: Thank you  @MarcusMüller the link to the thread